# Set PlaceHolder color of a textarea dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles

I'm trying to set the color of a placeholder inside a text-area which is my react component dynamically but failing to do so. I'm using CSS for styles where I set my default colors but these colors are updated later by the props. I'm able to set stuff like background-color, color etc easily but unable to set nested properties or pseudo selectors like `::placeholder`. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried setting it using plain JS and a couple of other inline styling practices but failing.

```
<div className="container-textarea">
              <TextAreaWrapper
                placeholder="Write message"
                style={color: props.color }
                />        
        </div>
```

//In style props, the color is set dynamically but I want to set the color of that placeholder dynamically as well.

I've tried doing this

```
const styles = {
color : props.color,
'::placeholder' : {
color : props.color
}
}
```

Comment: Specifically, what css-in-js package are you utilizing?

Comment: @technicallynick as you can see he's not using css-in-js at all. He use what is in pure react.

Comment: @jcubic, as he tagged "styles" which is ambiguous, I wanted to see if there was something I was missing.

Comment: @technicallynick jcubic is correct I'm not using css in js solutions or third-party libs. Just SCSS compiled to plain CSS which is utilized by the components.

Answer (score 2):

If you use style attribute you can use selectors only css properties.

```
style="color: red"
```

But there is a way to make it work dynamically, what you need is CSS variables (real spec name are Custom Properties) so you put this CSS into your style file:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: var(--placeholder-color);
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: var(--placeholder-color);
}
::placeholder {
  color: var(--placeholder-color);
}
```

then you can use React to add:

```
    <div className="container-textarea">
          <TextAreaWrapper
            placeholder="Write message"
            style={'--placeholder-color': props.color }
            />        
    </div>
```

Also I'm not sure you don't need `{{'--placeholder-color': props.color }}` one curly braces are react prop value and one are JS object inside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think that would work because I'm using SCSS and I believe, the variables in CSS and SCSS behave differently.

Comment: @BugggyBug they can work together you don't use variables in SCSS only those in CSS, they are specially created so they don't interfere with each other, that's why there is `--` at the beginning and not `$`.